# awk -- change after multiline context

Tags: awk

We need to change `Line3` only after specific two previous context of lines.
The specific contexts are:

```
Line2
LineEXTRA
```

File contains

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
-----
Line1
Line2
LineEXTRA
Line3
-----
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

The file need to have

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
-----
Line1
Line2
LineEXTRA
LineNEW
-----
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Our try

```
awk '/Line2/ { 
   print; getline; if ($0 ~ /Line3/) sub(/3/,"NEW")
}
{ print }' file
```

results

```
Line1
Line2
LineNEW
-----
Line1
Line2
LineEXTRA
Line3
-----
Line1
Line2
LineNEW
```

That's not what we want.

Our another try does not work at all

```
awk '/Line2\nLineEXTRA/ { 
   print; getline; if ($0 ~ /Line3/) sub(/3/,"NEW")
}
{ print }' file
```

Answer (score 4):

This code will give you the desired output

```
awk '/Line2/ { 
   print; getline; if ($0 == "LineEXTRA"){print;getline; sub(/3/,"NEW")}
}
{ print }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

@Dababi answer is perfect.

Another variant with gnu-sed

```
sed -zr 's/(Line2\nLineEXTRA\nLine)3/\1NEW/g' ex
```

(`sed -z` slurps the entire file, so we have direct access to multiline context. This solution should be avoid for gigabyte files)